# Prove that the function $φ:C(I)\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined as $φ(f):=f(1)$ for any $f\in C(I)$ is not continous with respect the $L_2$ topology.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

If $C(I)$ is the set of continous function on $I:=[0,1]$ then it is a well know result that the positions

1. $d_\infty(f,g):=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in I\}$
2. $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_0^1fg$

for any $f,g\in C(I)$ define a distance and an inner product. So let be now $\varphi:C(I)\rightarrow\Bbb R$ the function defined as
$$
\varphi(f):=f(1)
$$
for any $f\in C(I)$. So given $f_0\in C(I)$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb  R$ such that $a<b$ let be
$$
\delta:=\min\{f_0(1)-a,b-f_0(1)\}
$$
so that we observing that
$$
\varphi[B(f_0,\delta)]\subseteq(a,b)
$$
we conclude that $\varphi$ is continuous with repsect the distance $d_\infty$. Now my topology text claim that $\varphi$ is not continous with respect the topology on the inner product $\langle\,,\,\rangle$ but unfortunately I was not able to show this so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask to do this. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(C[0, 1],\|•\|_2)$

$\|f\|_2=[\int_{0}^{1} |f(t) |^2 dt]^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$\varphi:C(I)\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $$\varphi(f):=f(1)$$

Claim :$\varphi$ is not continuous.

First of all, $\varphi \in {\scr{L}}(C[0, 1], R) $ i.e $\varphi$ is linear.

A linear map between two normed space is  continuous iff continuous at $0$ .

To prove $\varphi$ is not continuous it is enough to show that it is not continuous at $0$ .

Choose, $(f_n) \subset C[0, 1]$ defined by $$f_n(t) =t^n$$

Then, $f_n \to 0 $ in the space $(C[0, 1], \|•\|_2) $(Verify)

But $\varphi(f_n) =f_n(1) =1 $ doesn't converges to $\varphi(\textbf{0}) =0$

Hence, $\varphi$ is not continuous at $0$ and hence discontinuous on the whole domain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, very well: I understand completely the proof. For sake of completeness I have only a question about the convergence of the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. So I know that the $L_2$-topology is contained in $d_\infty$-topology so that if I prove that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to zero with repscect $\mathcal T_{d_\infty}$ then it will converge also with respect to $\mathcal T_{L_2}$. So I have to prove that for any open neighborhood $U$ of zero there exists $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $f_n\in U$ for any $n\ge n_0$,

Comment: that is for any $\epsilon>0$ ther exists $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that $$f_n\in B(0,\epsilon):=\{f\in C(I):\sup|f|<\epsilon\}$$ so that I have to find an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\sup (t^n)<\epsilon$$ for any $n\ge n_0$, right?

Comment: However it seems to me that $\sup t^n=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ so that perhaps the sequece $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converges with respect $\mathcal T_{d_\infty}$? Could you help me, please?

Comment: Anyway we observe that $$\sqrt{\int_0^1t^n}=\sqrt{\Big[\frac 1{n+1}\cdot t^{n+1}\Big]_0^1}=\sqrt{\frac 1{n+1}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ so that $\|t^n\|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ if and only if $$\frac 1{n+1}<\epsilon^2$$ that is if and only if $$\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2}<n$$ and thus any $n$ greatest than $\frac{1-\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2}$ is such that $$f_n\in B_{L_2}(0,\epsilon)$$ for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$. So finally we conclude that $(t^n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges with respect $\mathcal T_{L_2}$. So Are correct the argumentation I gave?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro i am really happy to see your interest.$f_n\to 0 $  in $(C[0, 1], \|•\|_2) $ iff $\|f_n\|_2 \to 0 $ in $ \Bbb{R} $

$\|f_n\|_2^2 =\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(t) |^2 dt$

$\begin{align} \|f_n\|_2^2 &=\int_{0}^{1}t^{2n}dt\\&=\left .\frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right|_{0}^{1}\\&=\frac{1}{2n+1}\end{align} $

$\|f_n\|_2= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\to 0 $ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Okay, so I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are first countable (any normed space is first countable!) then $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $x_0$ is such that the sequence $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $f(x_0)$. Now the norm is continuous (more specifically if $X$ is a normed space then the norm is continuous with respect the corresponding vector topology) so that in the matter question if $f_n\rightarrow 0$ then $\|f_n\|_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to zero but I do not see the converse, sorry: so could you explain?

Comment: Well. This the definition of  convergence of a sequence in a normed linear space. $(X, \|•\|) $ be any nls and $(x_n) \subset X $ then $x_n\to x  $ if $\|x_n-x\|\to 0$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay, fine: all clear, now. Thanks very much for your assistance!!! See you soon.

Comment: I am also happy to help you.

Comment: Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432322/736008) too, please? I found an answer to a question I posed but I cannot be sure by my self it is good.